# Spring Boot - RSocket over websocket - Server responders not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-websocket, spring-rsocket

I am using Spring boot 2.6.3. This is a Spring webflux project and using RSocket over Websoocket for Notification.

**Server side:-**

build.gradle,

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsocket'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-rsocket'
```

Controller,

```
    @Controller
public class RSocketController {

    private static final List<RSocketRequester> CLIENTS = new ArrayList();

    @ConnectMapping
        void onConnect(RSocketRequester rSocketRequester) {
                rSocketRequester.rsocket().onClose().doFirst(() -> {
                    CLIENTS.add(rSocketRequester);
                }).doOnError(error -> {
                    
                }).doFinally(consumer -> {
    
                    
                    }
                }).subscribe();

    return Mono.empty();

    }).subscribe();

    rSocketRequester.route("client-status").data("Success!").send().subscribe();
   }

    @MessageMapping("send-notification")
    public void sendNotification(Mono<String> notification) {
        notification.subscribe(message -> {
            LOGGER.info("" + message);
        }, e -> LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e), () -> LOGGER.info("completed without a value."));

    }

    @GetMapping("/notify")
    public void giveCallback() {
        CLIENTS.get(0).route("callback-notification").data("CALLBACK TEST").send().subscribe();
    }
}
```

**Client Side:-**

```
class ClientHandler {

    @MessageMapping("client-status")
    public void statusUpdate(String status) {
        System.out.println("Called from server ========== -> Connection {}" + status);
    }

    @MessageMapping("callback-notification")
    public void requestResponse(String callback) {
        System.out.println("Received callback from server, request: " + callback);
    }

}

@Controller
public class ClientController {
   public ClientController(@Autowired RSocketRequester.Builder rsocketRequesterBuilder, RSocketStrategies strategies) {
        String client = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        SocketAcceptor responder = RSocketMessageHandler.responder(strategies, new ClientHandler());
        this.rSocketRequester = rsocketRequesterBuilder
                .rsocketStrategies(strategies).rsocketConnector(connector -> { 
                    connector.acceptor(responder);
                })
                .websocket(URI.create("ws://localhost:9091/rsocket/"));
        this.rSocketRequester.route("send-notification").data("Test Send").send().subscribe();      
    }
}
```

Here, From the client,

1. The client is able to connect to the server
2. The "connect-mapping" method gets invoked on a new connection on the server side and it sends status message to the client and I am able to see the message on the client side.
3. The "callback-notification" method on the server side is able to send notification to the client and I am able to see the message on the client side.

But, Calling send-notification on the client side is not executing sendNotification method on server side.

> this.rSocketRequester.route("send-notification").data("TEST Server Notification").send().subscribe();

Here, the client responders are working. But, the server responders are not working. Is there any special config required for the server responders.